# JFoenix Drawer .hide(); and .drawer(); functions are not working

Tags: javafx, drawer, jfoenix

I am tired on this point, JFoenix Drawer `.hide();` and `.drawer();` functions are not working

```
try {
    VBox box = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/chatroom/ui/chatingwindow/DrawerContent.fxml"));
    drawer.setSidePane(box);

    HamburgerBackArrowBasicTransition arrowBasicTransition = new HamburgerBackArrowBasicTransition(hamburger);
    arrowBasicTransition.setRate(-1);
    hamburger.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, (e) -> {
        arrowBasicTransition.setRate(arrowBasicTransition.getRate() * -1);
        arrowBasicTransition.play();

        if (drawer.isShown()) {
            drawer.hide();
        } else {
            drawer.draw();
        }
    });

} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(ChatingWindowController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

**why is that**, any Jfoenix tutorials are used that functions, but I couldn't use that?

Comment: I solved the problem by just adding `drawer.open()` and  `drawer.close()`
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It is because they do not exist it should be:

```
if (drawer.isOpened()) {
        drawer.close();
    } else {
        drawer.open();
    }
```

Comment: It's soloved sir! 
_Thank you!_